# Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets vs Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

These 2 libraries seem to serve a similar purpose: to securely store and control the access to tokens, passwords, API keys, and other secrets.

I have been using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault with some success, not for configuration secrets, but for keys.
Not until recently did I discover Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.

In [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/blob/master/releaseNotes/MicrosoftExtensionsConfigurationAzureAppConfiguration.md#300-preview-010550001-251---november-22-2019) I found this:

> Updated Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault with its successor Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets to resolve key vault references.

What are the distinguishing attributes of the 2 libraries, and how to determine the appropriate choice.

Should I interpret the release note to imply Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault is obsolete or will be deprecated?

Comment: Hope this link [Major changes from Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/CHANGELOG.md#major-changes-from-microsoftazurekeyvault) can help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What are the distinguishing attributes of the 2 libraries, and how to
>   determine the appropriate choice.

The package [Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/) is the most up-to-date version of the Key Vault client library, which is recommended to use for any new project. For main differences from the legacy one, see this 
[Major changes from Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/d9d93df6c75797a6027c125ab3ff61b2ac894102/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/CHANGELOG.md#major-changes-from-microsoftazurekeyvault). For usage, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-net).

The other package [Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/#) is now a legacy one, if you have some old projects which use it, you can keep using it. For usage, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-net-v3).

You can refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/previewing-azure-sdks-following-new-azure-sdk-api-standards/) for more details why these new client libraries(including Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets) are published.

> Should I interpret the release note to imply Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault
>   is obsolete or will be deprecated?

It is hard to say if the old one will be deprecated in the future. At least from the 
[Release History](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/d9d93df6c75797a6027c125ab3ff61b2ac894102/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/CHANGELOG.md#400-preview1-2019-06-28), it says the new one is not a direct replacement for `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault`(like other azure services, for example, `azure storage service` published a new version package recently, but not officially pronounced the old one is deprecated). But we suggest you should use the new one in any new create project like it says in the [doc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/#), a screenshot of this:

[image]

Hope it helps.